# MySQL: How can I use InnoDB locking to increment a non-primary value while preventing duplication of that value?

Tags: mysql, select, locking, innodb, sql-insert

I would like to increment a non-primary key value without the possibility of creating duplicates in the event that two queries check the `MAX()` of the non-primary key at the same time. I've found that a good way to accomplish this would be to use InnoDB's locking mechanism.

I have a table like this:

```
tbl
-----------------------
groupID | msgNum | msg
-----------------------
1       | 1      | text
1       | 2      | text
1       | 3      | text
2       | 1      | text
2       | 2      | text
```

I would like to insert a new row and to increment the `msgNum` for that row. What I'm worried about is that if I use `MAX(msgNum)` to calculate the next number, that two near-simultaneous queries would calculate `MAX(msgNum)` at the same time and then insert the same `msgNum` twice. So, I would like to lock the table, but only specifically lock the minimum possible, which would be to lock calculating the `MAX(msgNum)` for a specific `groupID` while also locking the ability to insert a new row of the specified `groupID`. Ideally, I would like to avoid locking reading from the table.

A possible solution would be this ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abc64e/2)):

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE groupID=1 FOR UPDATE;
INSERT INTO tbl
(groupID,msgNum,msg) VALUES
(1,(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(msgNum)+1,0) FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE groupID=1) AS a),"text");
COMMIT;
```

I think this solution should work, but I am not sure and after testing it I ran into an issue. Additionally, it's a difficult concept to test and I'd like to be sure so it would be better to know. What I'm not sure of is if the lock would prevent the `INSERT` query from beginning and thus preventing its calculation of `MAX(msgNum)`.

I did perform an initial test:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func runTest(sqlCon *sql.DB) {
    _, err := sqlCon.Exec(
        "START TRANSACTION",
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    _, err = sqlCon.Exec(
        "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE groupID=1 FOR UPDATE",
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    _, err = sqlCon.Exec(
        "INSERT INTO tbl " +
            "(groupID,msgNum,msg) VALUES " +
            "(1,(SELECT IFNULL(MAX(msgNum)+1,0) FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE groupID=1) AS a),\"text\")",
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    _, err = sqlCon.Exec(
        "COMMIT",
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}

func main() {
    sqlCon, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user1:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/Tests")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    sqlCon2, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user1:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/Tests")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    for i := 0; i < 40; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i)
        go runTest(sqlCon)
        go runTest(sqlCon2)
    }

}
```

I got between 7 and 52 rows inserted, no duplicates, but the tests did not finish (with 80 rows), saying `Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`:

```
$ go run main.go
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
```

Comment: Do you have a `UNIQUE` index on the column(s) in question?

Comment: I have a `UNIQUE` `AUTO_INCREMENT` `PRIMARY KEY` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you need transactions and explicit locking for this to run correctly. I would suggest having a single query that `select`s the last value, increments it and `inserts` a new row at once.

I would phrase the query as a `insert into ... select` statement:

```
insert into tbl(groupID, msgNum, msg)
select 1, coalesce(max(msgNum), 0) + 1, 'text'
from tbl
where groupID = 1
```

You would run this query with autocommit enabled. The database should be able to handle the concurrency for you, by queuing the `insert`s under the hood, so this should not generate deadlocks.

---

As a more general thought: I would not actually try to store `msgNum`. This is actually *derived information*, that can be computed on the fly when needed. You could just have an auto-incremented primary key on the table, and a view that computes `msgNum`, using window functions (available in MySQL 8.0)

```
create table tbl (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    groupID int
    msg varchar(50)
);

create view myview as
select 
    groupID,
    row_number() over(partition by groupID order by id) msgNum,
    msg
from tbl
```

You can then use a regular `insert` statement:

```
    insert into tbl(groupID, msg) values(1, 'text');
```

Upsides:

- the database manages the primary key for you under the hood
- your `insert` query is as simple and efficient as it gets (it does not require scanning the table, as in the other solution)
- the view gives you an always up-to-date perspective at your data, including the derived information (`msgNum`), with 0 maintenance costs

Comment: The concern I had was the case where a message is deleted. I didn't want to upset the numbering as it would cause conflicts with local storage. I suppose a boolean `deleted` field and overwriting the row's data could suffice.

Comment: @JVE999 - A deleted auto_inc is not reused except across a restart of the server.  MySQL 8.0 does not reuse deleted rows even after a power restart.

Comment: @RickJames Right, but `row_number() over(partition by groupID order by id) msgNum,` is not an `AUTO_INCREMENT`